# I cannot display an array of object by using console.log in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I created the array of object showing each movie title and rating. However I try to use console.log("You have watched " + movieObject.movieDB[0]);, the property, movieDB does not show, instead it shows "[object Object]".  Does anyone know the solution? The code below is exactly what I have done.

```
<code>
var movieObject = {
    movieDB: [
        {title: "In Brudges", rating: "- 5 stars"},
        {title: "Frozen", rating: "- 4.5 stars"},
        {title: "Mad Maz Fury Road", rating: "-5 stars"}
    ]
};


console.log("You have watched " + movieObject.movieDB[0]);
console.log("You have not seen " + movieObject.movieDB[1]);
console.log("You have seen" + movieObject.movieDB[2]);
console.log("You have not seen " + movieObject.movieDB[3]);
</code>
```

Comment: `console.log("...etc...",  movieObject...etc...)` instead or `JSON.stringify(movieObject..etc....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `movieDB` object in the `movieObject` array is its own object. JavaScript by default won't log it to the console as-is. Instead, you probably want to display the movie's title. To do that, reference the property: `movieObject.movieDB[0].title`. That will print the title of the `movieDB` object.

Comment: Hi @Matt U Thank you so much. I understood how to indicates each object inside an array. It works! Thank you so much. <code>movieObject.movieDB[0].title.rating</code> did not work. Instead, I wrote like <code>console.log("You have watched " + movieObject.movieDB[0].title + movieObject.movieDB[0].rating);</code>

Comment: Glad to help. Mine isn't the only answer given, so please choose the most helpful and mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. When you use concat operator with string javascript convert object to string, that' why you see [Object Object] in console. Pass the object as the second argument of console function.

**Working code**

```js
        var movieObject = {
            movieDB: [{
                title: "In Brudges",
                rating: "- 5 stars"
            }, {
                title: "Frozen",
                rating: "- 4.5 stars"
            }, {
                title: "Mad Maz Fury Road",
                rating: "-5 stars"
            }]
        };

        console.log("You have watched ", movieObject.movieDB[0]);
        console.log("You have not seen ", movieObject.movieDB[1]);
        console.log("You have seen", movieObject.movieDB[2]);
        console.log("You have not seen ", movieObject.movieDB[3]);
```

Comment: I will try to do that. Thank you. Also I will search what concat operation is.

Comment: The `+` is a concat operator.

Answer (score 0):

Because you accessing a Object through `movieObject.movieDB[0]`, If you want to get title property of this Object like `console.log("You have watched " + movieObject.movieDB[0].title)")`

Comment: I totally forgot that I had to add ".title" after the object. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to print complete object you have to write following code
console.log("You have watched " +JSON.stringify(movieObject.movieDB[0]));

To access title or rating you have to write following code:
console.log("You have watched " +JSON.stringify(movieObject.movieDB[0].title));

Comment: I didn't know that there is a method, "JSON.stringify...".  Thanks a lot.